# Blender 2.8 causes all other versions to not run!

Tags: error, windows, installation, versions, hardware

After installing 2.8 i use it for 5 min then it stops responding and crashes. I try to reopen and the console is blank and it never ends up working. All other versions of blender i have installed also stop working after this.

I've tried uninstalling all other blender versions and reinstalling, Updated all my drivers, restarted my pc, Closed all other programs, waited an hour for it to open. I've tried all of these multiple times with no luck!!! It seems to corrupt all versions of blender somehow!

This is clearly a bug with 2.8 unfortunately **:(** Any suggestions **?**
Should i just wait for the next update? and go back to 2.8beta?

Pc specs: 1080ti ftw3, i7-6700k, 16gb ddr4 ram, 2 1080p monitors, Win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Running older versions of Blender alongside 2.8**

Blender 2.8 removes older Blender version installed in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation`. If you want to run old versions of Blender alongside Blender 2.8 you will need to download their archive version which doesn't require installation.

1. [Download the desired version as .zip](https://download.blender.org/release/),
2. Extract it
3. Open the extracted folder
4. Create a shortcut to the blender.exe

   4.1 Right click on blender.exe and select *Create Shortcut*

   4.2 Rename the shortcut to differentiate it from the other Blender versions

   4.3 Drag the shortcut to your desktop

**How to troubleshoot your Blender 2.8 installation on Windows**

The first step is always to check if your system fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) to run Blender 2.8 and update your graphics drivers. Since you've already done both, you can continue with the following checks.

When Blender's UI doesn't start and it's frozen at the console, make sure that you haven't accidentally enabled *QuickEdit* mode by clicking into the command prompt. Simply press enter in the console and see if the execution resumes.

Blender offers batch scripts for debugging on Windows which can be found in the folder where Blender is installed. On Linux and macOS these have to be enabled by starting Blender from the terminal with one of the corresponding [debug flags](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#debug-options).

`blender_factory_startup.cmd` allows you start Blender with factory settings, in case your configuration or startup.blend is broken. The batch script uses the `--factory-startup` flag.

If that command allows you to open Blender properly, make the changes permanent.

1. *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*
2. *Edit > Preferences*

   2.1 Click the icon in the bottom left corner

   2.2 Click *Save Preferences*

If you're experiencing a crash that doesn't happen when starting Blender and you've got an updated graphics driver, then it's likely a bug. In order to help us identify if it's truly a bug and whether this is an issue already reported to the developers, you can run `blender_debug_log.cmd`. This batch script uses the `--debug` flag. Once Blender has started, try to perform the same steps that led to a crash. Once you were able to recreate the crash while running Blender from this batch script, upload the created log files (e.g. to Google Drive) and add a link to it in your question so we can take a look at it. Be aware that the `blender_system_info.txt` file contains detailed system information in case you don't want to share this information publicly.

Depending on the outcome we may advise you to create a bug report on https://developer.blender.org/ where the developers of Blender will try to resolve your problem. If we advise you to create a bug report and you're able to open Blender, go to *Help > Report a Bug*. In case you can't open Blender use the [template](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) and attach your system information file created in the previous step. Make sure to describe your problem in a concise but precise way. Add step by step instructions that allowed you to crash Blender. This is important so that the developers are able to reproduce the conditions that led to the crash. Finally if the crash only occurs with a certain project, you can attach your .blend file. Try to remove everything unnecessary out of the project, so that you have a minimum working example with which you can still reproduce the crash.

The other batch scripts or command line flags should only be used if a developer requests you to run these, because the log files can get quite big.

Comment: Thank you, thats alot of information for me to work with. Ill keep messing with it. Also my pc take 5 mins to boot now after installing 2.8 its very strange. It used to only take 5 secs. Ill play around with it for a day or so before I file a bug report. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: What ended up working was using version 2.81. It freezes sometimes but 2.8 would crash and not open and cause some other strange problems that required me to reboot my pc. So im 95% its a bug with 2.8 but thanks for helping narrow it down.